# What is the benefit of global VPC in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

What is the benefit of global VPC in GCP especially when subnet is the regional resource and communication between regions is depending on routing only?

Answer (score 0):

A [VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/overview)  is a global resource that consists of a list of regional virtual subnetworks (subnets) in data centers, all connected by a global wide area network. VPC networks are logically isolated from each other in Google Cloud.

If you mean Dynamic routing mode in Regional, Cloud Routers will learn routes only in the region in which they were created.
In Global ,routing lets you dynamically learn routes to and from all regions with a single VPN or interconnect and Cloud Router.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh for update. I would like to know what is the benefit of making VPC as global resource in GCP instead of regional one like with other cloud vendor. It would be grateful if u can share any use case of global VPC. Thanks !

Comment: VPCs were created to be global in nature so that traffic inside an isolated logical system could flow among its resources at different parts of the world, by default.This was to suit the business needs of ever-increasing organisations and services which are spread over multiple geographical locations as without the need of provisioning separate routes or peering, they could connect with their resources at multiple locations quickly.